# Prove that $T$ is not compact but $T^2$ is compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the linear operator $T: \ell_2\to \ell_2$ defined by for $x=x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)\in \ell_2$
$$
Tx=(0,\xi_1, 0, \xi_3, 0, \xi_5, 0,\dots, )
$$
Clearly, $T$ is bounded linear operator on $\ell_2$.

I try to prove that $T$ is not compact but $T^2$ is compact operator.

If we take $x_1=(1,0,0,\dots), x_3=(0,0,1,0,0,\dots),\dots, x_{2n-1}=(0,\dots, 0, 1,0,\dots)$ where $1$ appears on the $2n-1$-th coordinate. Then $\{x_{2n-1}\}\in \ell_2$ and is a bounded sequence in $\ell_2$.

**But I am stuck on how to show that $\{T x_{2n-1}\}$ does not has a convergent subsequence...**

I can show that it is not Cauchy: for $n\neq m$,
$$
\|Tx_{2n-1}-Tx_{2m-1}\|=\sqrt{2}
$$

Moreover, $T^2x=0$. Because $rank(T^2)=0$, $T^2$ is then compact.

Comment: What you're showing is much stronger than "the sequence is not Cauchy"! you're saying that the distance between any two distinct terms of the sequence is constant. In particular no subsequence is Cauchy and thus there are no convergent subsequences.

Comment: What I don't understand is why $T^2x = 0$ rather than $T^2x = Tx$?

Comment: @Michh But one sequence $\{x_k\}$ is not Cauchy, it could have a convergent subsequence ,right?

Comment: @Michh That because $T^2x=T(0,\xi_1,0,\xi_3,\dots)=(0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: Read my comment carefully. If you take any subsequence it will not be Cauchy because of the equality you wrote

Comment: Am I correct in saying that $T(\xi_0, \xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3,\ldots) = (0, \xi_1,0,\xi_3,\ldots)$?

Comment: @Michh I am confused is that I just choose one subsequence which is not Cauchy. But what we need to prove that any subsequence is not convergent. Can we prove that just by one divergent subsequence?

Comment: @Michh No, $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that there is a convergent subsequence $Tx_{n_i}$. In particular this subsequence is Cauchy. Then for $\epsilon = 1$, there exists $i_0$ such that for $i,j\geq i_0$, $\lVert Tx_{n_j}- Tx_{n_i}\rVert \leq 1$. This contradicts your equality. Thus there is no convergent subsequence.

Comment: So to say one operator $T$ is not compact, we just need to find one bounded sequence $\{x_k\}$ so that $\{Tx_k\}$ does not have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes this is how you negate "$T$ is compact". @Hermi

Answer (score 0):

Consider the operator $$
Sx=(\xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4,\dots, )
$$ Then $$STx=(\xi_1, 0, \xi_3, 0, \xi_5, 0,\dots, )
$$ The operator $ST$ is thus the orthogonal projection onto infinite dimensional subspace consisting of sequences which vanish at coordinates with even indices. Clearly any infinite dimensional  projection is not a compact operator.

Comment: For $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\dots)$, $STx=S(0,\xi_1,0,\xi_3,0,\xi_5,\dots)=(\xi_1, 0, x_3,\dots)$, right? Why do we have $ST=I$?

Comment: The operator $ST$ restricted to $\ell^2(2\mathbb{N}-1),$ i.e. sequences vanishing at even coordinates, acts as identity.